# Identifying faulty data in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

Apologies for asking a question that may have answers in some form or another on here, but I was unable to make any of those solutions work for me.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `application_id`, `unallocated_date`, `check_in_date`, `check_out_date` 
FROM `student_room` 
WHERE `user_id` = 17225
ORDER BY `application_id` DESC
```

It produces the following result:

```
user_id | application_id | unallocated_date    | check_in_date       | check_out_date   
--------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------
17225   | 30782          | 2018-02-04 14:32:29 | NULL                | NULL
17225   | 30782          | 2018-02-04 14:32:49 | NULL                | NULL
17225   | 30782          | 2018-02-04 14:32:51 | NULL                | NULL
17225   | 30782          | NULL                | NULL                | NULL
17225   | 30782          | NULL                | 2018-02-04 14:41:54 | NULL
```

The fourth row in the result is a fault in my data; it should look similar to the first three rows - these rows occur happens when a student was allocated a new room, and the previous one needs to be unallocated. In this case, the unallocation of row 4 did not actually happen due to either a historical bug in the system I am working on, or user error, but most likely the former.

How can I identify ALL such rows? My attempts with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` did not work, as I checked where all three date fields were NULL, but it did not pick up this particular user - so I was doing something wrong. My original query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS `count`, user_id FROM `student_room`
WHERE `unallocated_date` IS NULL
AND `check_in_date` IS NULL
AND `check_out_date` IS NULL
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1
ORDER BY `user_id` ASC
```

I tried various `INNER JOIN` attempts too, but I did not of them right...

The rows that I am interested in will have at least one entry with all three dates NULL, but also one where there is a check_in_date that is NOT NULL, as per this example. If I only had the first four rows, then the data could be correct, but the fifth row's presence makes the fourth row a faulty record - it should've been given an "unallocated_date" value at the time of the allocation of the room in the fifth row, which for some reason did not happen.

Comment: It’s not clear how this is a duplication problem. It looks like you just need to find the rows where all dates are null. What am I missing? Where does “duplication” enter in to the criteria?

Comment: like @MarcL. wrote, why can't you just check where all 3 columns are null?

Comment: A student can have a room allocated to them, but not yet be checked in. In such case, all three fields will be null, but not necessarily an error. So maybe the word duplication is incorrect here. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: so if a user has a row with a check_in_date that is not null then it shouldn't have a row where all date columns  are null?

Comment: @isaace: correct! Thank you for putting it more concise. However, it can happen that a check_in_date is not null and a check_out_date is not null, then the row with three null dates would be valid. Example: student checks in, does not like the room for some reason, checks out, and then gets assigned a new room.

Comment: so then in which case is having all 3 dates not valid?

Comment: @isaace: to further to my comment above, there has never been a case (bug) where the check_out_date is set, but check_in_date is not, so the example in the above comment will probably never happen.

Comment: You should never have an unallocated_date if you have a check_in and/or check_out date. unallocated_date only gets populated if the user has never checked in (never set foot in the room). If checked in before, you cannot unallocate this room, but needs to check_out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167190/discussion-between-kobus-myburgh-and-isaace).

Comment: your last comment has nothing to do with a row that has 3 null dates so now I am confused.

Comment: I cannot access chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together with a friend of mine, we made the following query that works. I have now learned that you can use "EXISTS" in MySQL. I saw it used when dropping or creating tables, but never like this. It ended up that this query solves the problem:

```
SELECT cte.user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT sro.user_id
    FROM student_room AS sro
    WHERE sro.unallocated_date IS NULL
    AND sro.check_in_date IS NULL
    AND sro.check_out_date IS NULL
    AND EXISTS ( 
        SELECT *
        FROM student_room AS sri
        WHERE sri.user_id = sro.user_id
        AND sri.student_room_id > sro.student_room_id
    )
    ORDER BY user_id DESC
)
AS cte
GROUP BY cte.user_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This query is the result of more than an hour of tinkering with records that was erroneous, so apologies if this appears to not match the question's requirements 100%, but it does solve the problem for me.